# How to build a simple transistor switch?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches, powermosfet

How to build the following:

1. A simple Transistor turn-OFF switch.
2. A simple transistors circuit that has its own power source, but when I apply a second alternate power source then it will switch to the second power source. (power sources are two 9V batteries). I don't want to use a relay!

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the simple switch circuit, note that the supply voltage shall not be over the Vgs max of the MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fldTj0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

For dual supply from 2 9V battery, two Schottky diodes would work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f61Y9Y.png)</sup>

Comment: You welcome. You can accept the answers if that has answered your question.

Comment: Sure, and how to do that please? I just voted as useful, is that all?

Comment: You can click the little V below the vote button to accept an answer

Comment: Hi Damien, I just simulated the first circuit, I got the concept, and works like charm. But still scratching my head about the second one, not sure how it works! I have a small fan that works on 9V battery, what I want to do is to plug it into an external power source which is around 9V to 12V and was thinking of a way that once I plug the 2nd power src it will disconnect from the 9V battery and starts using the 2nd power src. Again, I don't want to use any mechanical way to do that (i.e., relay ...etc).

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a 12V power source. Since the supply voltage would be higher than the battery, the circuit will not use any of the battery current when plugged. Another simple way is to use a DC barrel connector that has an integrated switch, so you can use this switch for the battery, when you connect the plug it will disconnect the battery.